# PHP AWS AssumeRole with InstanceProfile throws Exception

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

Trying to get this code to work.  We have it set up so we shouldn't need to read creds from a file. But it's still looking for them.

```
$provider = \Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider::instanceProfile();
call_user_func( $provider )->wait();
$config = [
        'profile' => 'default',
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'version' => '2011-06-15',
        'credentials' => $provider,
        'http' => [
            'connect_timeout' => 30,  // By default these wait indefinitely
            'timeout' => 60,
        ]
    ];
try {
    $stsClient = new StsClient($config);
    $stsResult = $stsClient->assumeRole([
            'RoleArn' => 'arn:aws:iam::1234:role/my-role',
            'RoleSessionName' => 'MySession'
        ]);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
   echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

But instead of picking it up from the instance, it's throwing an exception:

```
 Cannot read credentials from /home/user/.aws/credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
'profile' => 'default',
```

From the config.Using this means that it will always try to read from the filesystem for the credentials.